# Como interagir JavaScript + jQuery com CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Eu tenho uma classe em CSS que se chama `.codigo`. Eu queria que quando eu fosse usá-la, ela removesse a formatação HTML (exemplo: fazer que `<font></font>` apareça igual está aparecendo aqui no SO PT, usando o método `.text()`) e deixasse o span do mesmo estilo especificado pela classe. Como eu faço para interagir JS, jQuery e CSS?

Comment: Não entendi direito. Coloque seu código ai na pergunta.

Comment: Não entendi onde entra o JS e jQuery, não seria só o caso de estilizar via css?

Comment: Não. Quero usar o CSS para remover formatação HTML. Por exemplo: `<p>` igual no site, teria formatação HTML e sumiria.

Comment: `<font>` é uma tag que caiu em desuso, só é compatível até o HTML4, mas também não entendi qual o objetivo, tem como fazer um exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com jQuery e CSS, você pode recuperar o HTML e setar esse conteúdo como texto:

```js
$('.classe').text($('.classe').html())
```

E então definir um CSS para a fonte ficar com o espaçamento correto:

```css
.classe {
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Veja o exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEt5k/).

---

No entanto, eu desaconselho a usar esse esquema pois pode sofrer um ataque de [XSS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) no caso de mostrar conteúdo de usuário. O ideal seria você fazer um escape do HTML no lado do servidor.

---

**Update**

Sem Javascript, seria possível colocar o HTML dentro de um `<textarea>` ou substituindo os caracteres especiais do HTML no servidor:

Exemplos:

```html
<textarea>Código   <strong>html</strong> aqui!</textarea>
<pre>Código   &lt;strong&gt;html&lt;/strong&gt; aqui!</pre>
```

Veja o [jsfiddle desse exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/sgAYp/).

Uma forma de substituir os caracteres usando php é com a função [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Note que o `textarea` também é vulnerável ao *Cross Site Scripting*, por exemplo se um usuário conseguir escrever um valor como o apresentado a seguir:

```html
</textarea><script>....</script><textarea>
```

Comment: Agora eu entendi o que ele queria!

Comment: Isso também funciona se, por exemplo, eu quiser colocar um fundo azul?

Comment: @LucasHenrique Acrescente o atributo `background-color: #AAAAFF` no CSS. Claro, ajuste a cor para sua necessidade.

Comment: E utluiz, há como fazer isso sem JS? Sério, eu realmente não sou muito fan de JS, apesar de todo mundo usar em todas as coisas.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Atualizei a resposta com as opções de textarea e `pre`.

Comment: O pre é o que eu não queria usar (`&lt;` e esse tipo de coisa), mas o text area é uma boa ideia!

Comment: @LucasHenrique Note que se for exibir dados de usuários em textarea sem devido *escape*, alguém pode injetar um script na sua página assim: `</textarea><script>....</script><textarea>`.

Answer (score 1):

Se você está querendo adicionar a sua formatação em uma tag especifica do seu HTML, seria algo assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('font').addClass('codigo');
});
```

Isso vai adicionar sua classe código em todas as tag `font` após o carregamento.

Mas você pode obter o mesmo resultado modificando seu CSS dessa maneira:

```
.codigo, font {
    /* meu estilo */
}
```

No caso a virgula indica que as mesmas regras que se aplicam a classe `.codigo` vão se aplicar a todos elementos `<font>` da sua página.